# Twitter REST API request_token/access_token login. How can I avoid asking for permission every login?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using a first call to `https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token`. In this call Twitter asks the user to give permissions to my app (I just ask for READ permission). Once the user accepts I get the `request_token` with which I can ask for the `access_token` (`https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token`) and from that point on I can do requests to Twitter REST API on behalf of the user.

Basically this works  but every time the user logs in, the permissions window comes up to allow permissions. How can I avoid this?